# JWT authentication for public resources

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

I try to check JWT Access Tokens in server middleware zone

If JWT token is expired and if resources is only for authorized users then I return 401 code

But if user requests public resources (granted for anonymous users) with JWT token should I return 401 code when token is expired or not?

How do I notify a user that their token is invalid?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public resources do not require securing, so you should ensure that your server middleware does not run for these requests, and whether or not a valid JWT is sent, you will then return the resource with a 200 status code.

This is usually done by adopting a path convention such as the following. If resources are public you will not care if a hacker accesses them.

```
/public/docs
/public/news
```

I have seen people protect public resources in a basic way, eg via a fixed API key, to limit denial of service risks, though I wouldn't usually recommend this. It is worth mentioning since in that case those paths would use a different server middleware.

For secured endpoints, validate the JWT properly and follow [Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-best-practices/):

- Use a library to verify the signature, expiry, issuer and audience
- Return a 401 status if any of these fail
- Then move onto business authorization checks using scopes and claims - eg checking a user is allowed to access the actual data requested
- If business authorization fails, return a 403 (or 404 - not found for user) status

Comment: Thank you! I didn't use "/public/" or "/restricted/" route. I used "/" for restricted data and excluded from this base route public routes (/sign_in, sign_up etc).

In this way, the URL looks more beautiful. And when changing the data type from public to restricted, I don't have to change the URL